# C# List to Array Problem

Tags: c#

Still new to C# so be gentle :)

I have some code which reads in a CSV file and stores the output in a List. I used a List instead of an Array as the number of entries in the CSV is undetermined. Once the List is created from the file I then want to pass it to a Shell sort method as this is the purpose of the program. To do this I first want to convert the list to an array of integers. I have tried the `.ToArray` method but it doesnt seem to be working for me. I get an exception

> Cannot Implicilty convert type `String[][]` to `string[]`.

I know I am doing something stupid but cant seem to find out what... Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Import DAT file and format it.
public int[] ImportDat(string path)
{
    List<string[]> loadedData = new List<string[]>();

    loadedData.Clear();

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader readCSV = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            string[] row; 

            while ((line = readCSV.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                row = line.Split(',');
                loadedData.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Import Failed. Please check the file is in the same folder as the executable");
    }

    string[] MyArray = loadedData.ToArray();

    //temp Array to return a value
    int[] numbers = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: will each row only have one entry (i.e. one column) or multiple columns? If the later, what do you want to do with that? sort the row then sort the columns, or just add all entries in the row to a common list then sort the whole list?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you really want a one dimensional list of numbers from your CSV file, but you are treating each row separately right now. If that is the case then use:

```
 loadedData.AddRange(row);
```

instead of:

```
 loadedData.Add(row);
```

and declare loadedData as `List<string>`. Now you still would have to do the conversion to int, since your method returns a list of int.Using LINQ you could do:

```
List<int> results = loadedData.Select(s=> Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();
```

Your method also could be fully expressed with LINQ like this:

```
public int[] ImportDat(string path)
{
    List<int> result = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                           .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                           .SelectMany(s => s)
                           .Select( s=> Convert.ToInt32(s))
                           .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1, best answer, but dirty data/validation data will need a wrapper of the Convert.ToInt32 call. Just as information for the HCompston.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable loadedData is a List of string arrays.  Calling .ToArray() on it will return a string[][] (2 dimensional array), not a string[].

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the list and convert the numbers right away?

```
public int[] ImportDat(string path)
{
     List<int> loadedData = new List<int>();

     loadedData.Clear();

     try
     {
        using (StreamReader readCSV = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            string[] row;

            while ((line = readCSV.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                row = line.Split(',');
                foreach(var token in row)
                {
                    loadedData.Add(Convert.ToInt32(token));
                }
            }
        }
     }
     catch
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Import Failed. Please check the file is in the same folder as the executable");
     }

     return loadedData.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring loadedData as a list of string arrays. You should just do

```
List<string> loadedData = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each item in your List, is an array of strings.
it's not a list of string.
hench, you should make your "MyArray" a two dimensional array of strings.
in other words, an array of arrays of strings.
so in short: string[][] MyArray = loadedData.ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can modify this code to suit your needs?

```
   List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();
        string input = "2,4,6,3";
        string[] numbersStringArray  = input.Split(',');
        foreach (var numberString in numbersStringArray)
        {
            numbersList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(numberString));
        }

        int[] numbersArray = numbersList.ToArray<int>();
```